# Routing with web forms and MVC in one project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-applications, webforms, asp.net-mvc-routing, vs-web-site-project

I'm trying to convert an old Website project to a web application. I've managed to get the project set up and the files copied over and references set up and all that. The issue that I am having is that the routing has totally changed now and instead of this:

```
../quotes/Transmittals.aspx
```

I get:

```
../quotes/Transmittals
```

which is great, I love it. But in the old website project all of the ajax calls are set up with these types of routes:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/quotes/Transmittals.aspx/GetContractTypes",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {   
    ...            
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {                
    ...
    }
});
```

And in the code behind of the .aspx page:

```
 <System.Web.Services.WebMethod>
    Public Shared Function GetContractTypes() As String
        Using _Repo As New Repository
            Return ServiceCallResult.SendJSONResult(_Repo.GetContractTypesByLogin(SessionManager.GetCurrent.LoginID))
        End Using
    End Function
```

And now the path: `/quotes/Transmittals.aspx/GetContractTypes` is a big 404. If I remove the .aspx from the path, it is found, but the `WebMethod` is never hit.

The route config I have is the standard generated one when you create a new web application:

```
Public Module RouteConfig
    Sub RegisterRoutes(ByVal routes As RouteCollection)
        Dim settings As FriendlyUrlSettings = New FriendlyUrlSettings()
        settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent
        routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings)

        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}")

        routes.MapRoute(
            name:="Default",
            url:="{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults:=New With {.action = "Index", .id = UrlParameter.Optional}
        )
    End Sub
End Module
```

Is there something I need to put in the route config or do I need to change my ajax paths or what?

Comment: You could leverage `routes.IgnoreRoute` to do this; I don't know if you have to hard-code each URL, or could develop a pattern...

Comment: I can use IgnoreRoute to ignore all .aspx pages and that works, but then the "friendly" url functionality pretty much goes out the window, and I kinda like it - especially when I'm going to mix aspx and mvc in this new web app. Maybe if I can set up ignore routes for ajax calls?

Comment: You might be able to setup an ignore where there is .aspx in any part of the URL, so that is what I would specifically research... I don't think, but am not 100% sure, that you can differentiate between AJAX and standard.